# Getting the activecontrol name and value from a multipages form

Tags: vba, excel

I've been searching the web for a solution for a couple of months without any success.
I created in `Excel 2010` a `UserForm` with multipages. I'm trying to write a function that will get the `activecontrol` name and value.

Until now, I succeeded in getting the name of the control using this command 
`Me.MultiPage1.Pages(Me.MultiPage1.Value).ActiveControl.Name` but the only thing I managed to do with it was to set it in to a variable as a string.
I still need to get it's value.

I really appreciate any help.
blackmail

Comment: Isn't `Me.MultiPage1.Value` what you're looking for?!?

Comment: that's will give the page, i'm searching for the field in it.

Comment: Then `Me.MultiPage1(Me.MultiPage1.Value).ActiveControl.Value` will do! Just tested it! :-)

Comment: @PeterAlbert You should post your comment as an answer!

Comment: Great, now @user2031718 should close the question by clicking the checkmark next to the answer... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the value of the last active control in the MultiPage control with this code:

```
Me.MultiPage1(Me.MultiPage1.Value).ActiveControl.Value
```

However, I'm not sure that every kind of control has a `.Value` property, so make sure that all your different controls in the Multipage has one - or include a proper error handler!